# How to store ajax response in a global variable so that the result can be used from anywhere?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to keep a ajax result into a variable which I will use later. The problem is when I want to use the variable it returns null. I understand that it will for asynchronous programming. But I need to keep the result in a variable.
Also I don't want to use async=false method.
Below is my code I tried so far.

```
var column_values=[];
                    $.ajax({
                                url: "/get_value/",
                                type: "POST", // http method                                
                                dataType: "json",
                                async:"false",
                                data:{
                                    json:prev_value
                                },
                                success: function(data){
                                    column_values=data;
                                    
                                },
                                error: function(error){
                                    alert(error)
                                }
                            });
```

When I tried to access the value of column_values in another function it lengths returns 0.

```
function get_value(){
  let values=column_values.length;
  // Here it returns 0
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Long answer short: when `get_value()` is invoked your async request has not returned the data yet.

Comment: The question is: *when* are you calling `get_value()`?

Comment: I understand. But how can I store the result in variable? Otherwise I need to call the ajax request every time.

Comment: I am calling get_value() later time. It has no relation with the ajax call. I just want to use the result from variable. @ Chris G

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/w0kjsfru/ Please provide a [mcve] and explain why this isn't a duplicate. Currently we can just guess what _"later time"_ means and what the actual problem is.

Comment: At first the example you have shown it use async : false method which is depreciated. Second,This is not duplicate because all the example I have seen they call the ajax multiple time to get the result. But I want to call the ajax one time and keep the result in a variable. For example: I call the ajax on form load and store the result in a variable. Then after a button click I want to access the variable to get the value.@jabaa